# Coverall module fails to parse string(s)

Tags: mocha.js

I'm testing my application with mocha along with istanbul.
For coverage and testing i'm using the following entries in my package.json

```
  "test:integration": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test mocha --timeout 20000 src/api/tests/integration",

  "coverage": "nyc report --reporter=text-lcov | coveralls",
```

The test passes, but when doing `yarn coverage` i'm getting an error

```
$ nyc report --reporter=text-lcov | coveralls
[error] "2018-08-04T21:25:57.261Z"  'error from lcovParse: ' 'Failed to parse string'
[error] "2018-08-04T21:25:57.263Z"  'input: ' ''
[error] "2018-08-04T21:25:57.263Z"  'error from convertLcovToCoveralls'

C:\Users\Mikk\Documents\GitHub\backend\node_modules\coveralls\bin\coveralls.js:18
        throw err;
        ^
Failed to parse string
```

Any ideas? I even tried to reinstall the node modules, but that doesn't seem to fix anything.

Comment: I've faced a similar problem, hope [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60362121/how-to-configure-coveralls-with-github-action/65615948#65615948) might help you a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same set up in my package.json file and the same issues earlier today but I **fixed it by refreshing** my repo attached to Coveralls.io

After refreshing, I restarted build on Travis CI and it worked.

***Ensure you have the following in your project root dir***

.coveralls.yml -- It should contain repo_token if you're using a public repo